# How to arrange circles to use lowest possible space?

Tags: javascript, math, optimization, geometry

I'm building a configuration tool with Javascript that calculates the measurements of a cable trunc in different ways. Basically, you can enter the amount of cables and the cable diameter. Now I want to visualize these cables as circles with the given diameter and automatically pack them together to take up as little space as possible. Here are two examples:

7 cables packed together:

[image: 7 cables]

48 cables:

[image: 48 cables]

As you can see, I already tried to achieve that by using a physics engine ([physics.js](http://jonobr1.github.io/Physics/#)) and let gravity automatically arrange the elements optimally. This somehow works for small numbers but it takes quite a while to finish for larger numbers of elements ( > 20) and it doesn't always produce the best possible result. Besides that, I think that this way is a little over the top.

Is there a neat way of calculating the position of *x* given circles with diameter *d*? Is there perhaps even a framework or similar that takes care of such tasks? I'm curious about your ideas, thanks in advance. Oh, and by the way, this isn't homework - I'm 35+ :-D

Comment: Just to give you a starting point: when you look at circles packed around another circle, when all of them are of the same diameter, you may notice the centers of outside circles make a nice regular hexagon. A hexagonal grid is, in fact, the most optimal way of packing circles. Maybe you can work out (or google) the math from here :)

Comment: @pawel: +1 I had to google it! :)  Evidently some mathemeticians and physicists have enjoyed this query also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Comment: Thanks, Pawel & Mark, I think I BASICALLY got it ;-) Erich's packing center is a good resource for further investigation: http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/packing.html

Comment: Small world!! I graduated from Stetson University in 19-way-long-ago!

Comment: Mmm, could still be homework.. :-P But I believe it's off-topic for SO as it's more a mathematical problem than a code problem. Why not check [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) (however, blurry lines).

Comment: @pawel: I don't think that using an hexagonal packing is optimal for 4 cables if the measure is the diamater (defined as maximum distance between two points)

Comment: @Robert Gravity may not produce optimal results, but I'm really impressed with the approach.

Comment: @Ken - I chose SO because besides the math aspect I primarily wanted to know if there already exists an implementation for this kind of packing problems.

Comment: @Llepwryd: You're right, it isn't optimal and I'll definitely go for Arrieta's or Phillip's solution - but if you don't need perfect results, it's a nice eyecatcher watching them arrenge themselves ;)

Comment: Viz "takes quite a while to finish for larger numbers of elements ( > 20) and it doesn't always produce the best possible result" - nature is trying to do this when a crystal forms, and yes it is slow and imperfect; cf the expense of pure crystals. Nature also gives you the ideal packing in 2d; graphene (a 2d crystal) is hexagonally packed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "lowest possible space" you mean "contained in the smallest area" (or "enclosed by the tightest convex hull"), you may find it useful to check the [article in Wikipedia about circle packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing):

> In two dimensional Euclidean space, Joseph Louis Lagrange proved in
>   1773 that the lattice arrangement of circles with the highest density
>   is the hexagonal packing arrangement, in which the centres of the
>   circles are arranged in a hexagonal lattice (staggered rows, like a
>   honeycomb), and each circle is surrounded by 6 other circles.

[image: Circle Packing In Hexagonal Lattice]

Could you base your algorithm on this finding? What I am thinking is this: start with the "trivial" hexagon arrangement that covers at least the number of cables, and then start iterating over the outer circles and remove the one which is the farthest from the center circle. Continue until you are left with the exact number of circles you needed.

If you do this, you save the time of computing "what you already know". That is, if you had seven circles, you know that it is a hexagon with a circle in the middle, period. If you had eight circles, you start with the hexagon of 12 circles, which contains the hexagon of six circles, which contains the one circle: a total of 19 circles (12 + 6 + 1). You start removing circles from the outer hexagon (the one with 12 circles) until you have removed 11, and you are left with 8 circles (1 + 6 + 1) in optimal arrangement.

Comment: Or you can do the reverse and simply add circles in a hexagonal pattern. The next step is to figure out an algorithm to calculate the center coordinates quickly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Arrieta, that makes things clear. I agree with slebetman, I'll probably start with the center and keep adding circles around it hexagonally. I accepted your answer because it provides the best solution (lowest area != lowest enclosing circle diameter) for same-size circles.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm will not always find the proven best solution (which is quite hard, because [for most numbers over 13 the best known configuration has not yet been proven to be ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)), but in most cases it should at least give a solution which is "quite good":

> - Start with one center-circle and place it
> - for each additional circle
>
>   - find the angle from where it gets closest to the center-circle without 
>       overlapping an already placed circle
>   - place it there

The time-complexity of this algorithm depends on how efficiently you can find the closest position for a new circle. With some optimizations you should be able to get this to be linear to the number of circles. That would mean that the overall complexity of the algorithm would be `n²`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As far as I can see, your solution also works, but it is a more general approach as you can use it for cases where you have varying circle diameters (which could become interesting in a latter version).